# Checking Dataframe for Changes for Particular Users

Tags: python, pandas

```
ID  Date   T   Country 
1   2/5/12 120 US
1   2/4/13 110 US
1   3/4/12 120 France
2   3/4/12 110 US
2   3/5/12 140 US
3   3/4/12 133 US
```

I am trying to write a code that for every unique ID will see if the T column went below a threshold (i.e below 110) or if they changed countries. If so, I want there to be another column named Treatment that has 1 corresponding to that ID. How would I achieve this?

Basically:

for given ID 
    if T < 110 -> 1 
    if Country changes -> 1
    else-> 0

Expected output:

ID  Date   T   Country Treatment

1   2/5/12 120   US     1

1   2/4/13 110   US     1

1   3/4/12 120 France   1

2   3/4/12 110 US       0

2   3/5/12 140 US       0

3   3/4/12 133 US       0

Comment: please add another part which shows expected output. Also please explain the process/ steps in more detail. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `apply` to get a Boolean Series indicating whether your condition has been met for each ID, and `astype` to convert to 0/1.  Once you have this, use it with `map` on the ID column.

```
def check_condition(grp):
    return (grp['T'] < 110).any() | (grp['Country'].nunique() > 1)

cond_map = df.groupby('ID').apply(check_condition).astype(int)
df['Treatment'] = df['ID'].map(cond_map)
```

Or, if you don't want to create the intermediary `cond_map` you can put the `groupby` within the `map`:

```
df['Treatment'] = df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID').apply(check_condition).astype(int))
```

The resulting output:

```
   ID    Date    T Country  Treatment
0   1  2/5/12  120      US          1
1   1  2/4/13  110      US          1
2   1  3/4/12  120  France          1
3   2  3/4/12  110      US          0
4   2  3/5/12  140      US          0
5   3  3/4/12  133      US          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the power of pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# Future note: if you could include your sample data like this that would save 
# those who are trying to help you a LOT of time :)
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,1,2,2,3],
                   "Date":["2/5/12","2/4/13","3/4/12","3/4/12","3/5/12","3/4/12"],
                   "T":[120,110,120,110,140,133],
                   "Country":["US","US","France","US","US","US"]})

# Using a dictionary to map into the original DataFrame
d = {}

# For each ID 
for i in range(len(df["ID"].values)):
    unique_id = df["ID"][i]

    # Breaking the original data into rows to check each
    # instance of 'T'
    sub_frame = df.loc[i, :]

    # Checks both cases ('T'<110 and unique('Country')>1) at once
    if sub_frame["T"] < 110 or len(df.loc[df["ID"]==unique_id, "Country"].unique()) > 1:
        d[unique_id] = 1
    else:
        d[unique_id] = 0

df["Treatment"] = df["ID"].map(d)

print(df)

  Country    Date  ID    T  Treatment
0      US  2/5/12   1  120          1
1      US  2/4/13   1  110          1
2  France  3/4/12   1  120          1
3      US  3/4/12   2  110          0
4      US  3/5/12   2  140          0
5      US  3/4/12   3  133          0
```

Note: Your question asks to consider each *unique* ID, but since you want to find `T<110` for each instance then you can't do for each unique ID (since there are multiple instances of single ID - you'd be trying to compare a value `110` across an array `[120,110,120]`.